# Excel Solver gives different solutions when run with no changes

Tags: excel, solution, solver

I have a spread sheet with 5 columns, A, B, C, D and E, all the same length all containing numerical data.

Columns A, B, and C  all have values from -10 to +10, column D is the results. in column E I have an If AND formula that only shows the appropriate result from D if A, B, or C fall within a range. The range is set by separate cells that the IF AND formula references.

I want the solver to find an optimal range for A, B, and C that maximizes the results in E by changing the ranges for A, B, C.

for example the solver may return;

A must be between 0 and 5, B can be between -10 and +10, C is -2 to 0. This criteria maximizes the total in the adjacent cells E.

Everything in the spreadsheet works as it should however each time I run the solver a different solutions pops up without me changing any of the data or doing anything differently.  Am I missing some logic with how the solver works? I believe it should always find the optimal solution which should always be the same if nothing else changes

Comment: What solver settings are you using? If you are using the evolutionary solver you would expect different results with different runs.

Comment: I am using the evolutionary one, the others didnt seem to work as well.  Shouldnt it always be the same result either way though?

Answer (score 1):

[Evolutionary algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) find *heuristic* solutions by a simulation of biological evolution. They work by creating randomly generated population of candidate solutions and uses the objective function that you are trying to optimize to judge the fitness of the candidate solutions (with better values of the objective function corresponding to fitter solutions). Fitter solutions are allowed to mate with each other (in a way with a fair amount of randomness thrown in) with the mating solutions generating children constructed by a combination of random-cross over and mutation. Even a simple run of an evolutionary algorithm will involve hundreds of thousands or even millions of calls to random number generators, hence no two runs are the same. If all goes well, all runs should give solutions whose values are *approximately* the same -- though problems with a great deal of local optima sometimes presents a problem which has no easy solution.

Comment: Thank you, would what values I have initially set in the cells that it changes have any effect on the algorithms?  Also would you recommend using the solver in a different way for what im trying to accomplish? (A separate range for each of the 3 columns that will maximize the total in the adjacent column?) The other solver methods wouldnt work at all for me

Comment: Maybe describe your problem in detail in a separate question. Stack Overflow questions shouldn't mutate in the comments to distinct albeit related questions.